# Ember-data Find nested models with parent

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

***How can I tell Ember to retrieve not only a list of matches, but also get objects for each of the players associated?***

In my router, I have:

```
App.MatchesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Match.find()
```

Here is what my JSON data is for `localhost:3000/matches.json`

```
{"matches":[{"id":1,"player_one":{"id":1,"name":"Lex"},"player_two":{"id":20,"name":"Superman"}}]}
```

**Update to provide more info 03/15/13**

Here is the `matches.emblem` (Emblem being the haml-slim-like-handlebars)

```
#matches
  each match in controller
    linkTo "match" match class="panel six columns"
      p Match between {{match.player_one.name}} and {{match.player_two.name}}
```

We are successfully getting the `Match` objects, and I can call the `id` on it (not shown), but we need to get the names of `match.player_one` and `match.player_two`, which are returning undefined.

**Match**

```
App.Match = DS.Model.extend
  player_one: DS.belongsTo('App.Player')
  player_two: DS.belongsTo('App.Player')
```

**Player**

```
App.Player = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think your `Player` model has to reference the `Match` with a `belongsTo` as well. And you'd have to tell your adapter to embed the child object. Something like: `DS.RESTAdapter.map( 'App.Match', { player_one: { embedded: 'load' } });` ... something like this.. but I'm not 100% sure of how to properly do this, I just know it's something along these lines (I use a modified version of the adapter)

Comment: Thanks for thinking about this, is there a reason you use a modified version of the adapter? Maybe that's something I should be looking into as well.

Comment: The only reason I use a different adapter/serializer is because I use .NET backend, which is slightly different from Rails. It is part of the [Ember Web API template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/emberjs-template) in the .NET world. You can also see it in use [here](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/Ember-Contact-Management-WebAPI/tree/master/Ember-Contact-Management-WebAPI/Scripts/app). For Rails, use the built-in RESTAdapter

Answer (score 0):

If you always returns the players with a match, you probably want to declare the players as embedded.

You would write something like this:

```
Adapter.map(App.Match, {
  player_one: {embedded: load},
  player_two: {embedded: load},
});
```